# PHP extension for sqlsrv.so and pdo_sqlsrv.so result in not found for library dependencies

Tags: php, linux, static-libraries, sqlsrv

Trying to create sqlsrv.so and pdo_sqlsrv.so files to use with PHP. When I compile the .so files from source and then run a `ldd` on them, I get an output with all of the library paths (see below). But if I move the .so files to another server, the library files are not attached. How can I package the dependencies so that the .so file is portable to different servers?

If it helps, we did make a directory with the required libraries in `/var/www/html/library/msodbc/` but we can't figure out how tell the configure command to point there instead of the system libraries.

Output of `ldd sqlsrv.so` on first machine:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc253a1000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbf208ea000)
libodbc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2 (0x00007fbf20677000)
libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007fbf2045c000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbf20246000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbf20029000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbf1fc5f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbf1f956000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbf20ebe000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbf1f752000)
```

But output when the file is moved to a different server:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe643f4000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f447f694000)
libodbc.so.2 => not found
libodbcinst.so.2 => not found
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f447f47e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f447f0b4000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f447edab000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f447fa16000)
```

Comment: You're only missing ODBC. I'd say it'd be easier to just install libodbc on the other server than packing a static binary with libc and other stuff. (Just a thought, I'm mainly a Windows guy.)

Comment: Thanks. We thought that as well, but we don't have control over the other server and the people who do are not willing to install it – though it would make things easier!